# Custom Module Controller: Invalid security or form key. Please refresh the page

Tags: magento2, module, magento2.3, admin-controller, form-key

I have a custom module with an admin controller, but when I try to access from the administration page I get the following error:

[image]

My controller is in **Controller/Adminhtml/Login/Index.php**

```
class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action {...}
```

and the route decalaration in **etc/adminhtml/routes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="oct" frontName="oct">
            <module name="Oct_Oct" before="Magento_Backend" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

the layout is in **view\adminhtml\layout\oct_login_index.html**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="oct\oct\Block\Adminhtml\Login\Index" name="oct_login_login" template="login.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>

    </body>
</page>
```

when i put the cursor on the adminhtml link get:

```
https://store.com/administrador55/oct/login/index/key/526f769ae4f621ffbda151c2a48015933d510d2d64fe2047abc29cbc29c27e27/
```

---

Debug:

[image]

any idea?

Thnks

Comment: Please Check the route that you have defined is it created or not. This error occurs due to wrong route. For example if you have action/url **feedback/customer/create** then **feedback** should be your route, **customer** your controller and **create** is your action of controller.

Comment: i added more information

Comment: The error may be in your `ui_component` Can you please update the code here?

Comment: Is it a typing mistake or you have named controller folder  **Cotroller** like this? And if its typing mistake share your **layout** and **ui_component** xml files.

Comment: it was a typing mistake.

Comment: i added layout.xml, i dont have ui_component.xml file

Comment: I have added the solution in anwser check if it works. Or else check your login.phtml file.You should add vendor_module in your template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I have finally found the solution.**

The mistake was that i had the module folder like:

```
../code/Oct/oct
```

I changed it for

```
../code/Oct/Oct
```

and everything works correctly.

Thank you very much everyone for your help and answers

Comment: where did you find that?

Comment: thanks, save lot a time

Answer (score 2):

Please Replace your **oct_login_index.xml** with this code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_ 
    configuration.xsd">
     <body>
          <referenceContainer name="content">
              <block class="oct\oct\Block\Adminhtml\Login\Index" name="oct_login_login" template="vendor_module::login.phtml"/>
          </referenceContainer>

    </body>
</page>
```

In above code i have added **vendor_module**.You should provide vendor_module to point your file in template where you define your **phtml** file.

Comment: Helped @keval Kadiya

Answer (score 0):

This could be the max_input_vars problem but without seeing more of your code I am not sure.

Set max_input_vars to 10000 in php.ini and restart your web server (or php-fpm) and then give it another go.

Comment: I have max_input_vars = 100000

Answer (score 0):

Below solution is worked for me:

> app\code\Vendor\Module\etc\adminhtml\routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="oct" frontName="oct">
            <module name="Vendor_Module" before="Magento_Backend" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

> app\code\Vendor\Module\view\adminhtml\layout\oct_login_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Login\Index" name="oct_login_login" template="Vendor_Module::login.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Here block class `Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Login\Index` should extends `Magento\Backend\Block\Template`.

> app\code\Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Login\Index.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Login;

class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->addBreadcrumb(__('Test Page'), __('Test Page'));
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Test Page'));
        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

> app\code\Vendor\Module\view\adminhtml\templates\login.phtml

```
Add your content here
```

Then Final result will be:

[image: Result Screenshot]

Answer (score -1):

You need to debug this to get where the issue is .
Open in your local envoirment

> ```
> vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php 
> vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php
> ```

and add this :

```
$backtrace = [];
$debugBackTrace = debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS);
foreach ($debugBackTrace as $item) {
    $backtrace[] = @$item['class'] . @$item['type'] . @$item['function'] . "\n";
}
$writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/invalid_form_key.log');
$logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info(__FUNCTION__);
$logger->info($backtrace);
$logger->info('***************************************************************');
```

Check the result it here `/var/log/invalid_form_key.log` .

Comment: Do I have to do something after writing this code? or will it work directly?

Comment: no just paste the code , this is an example dev\tests\api-functional\framework\Magento\TestFramework\TestCase\Webapi\Adapter\Rest\DocumentationGenerator.php of using debugtrace method. In the moment you replicate the issue with form key , check if the log will be updated

Comment: i added the exit